# Is Paypal Payment Method Tokens Api allowed in Switzerland app account?

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to save card payment method using Payment Method Tokens Api in sandbox mode. For example i used American Express test card [removed], but when i tried to create setup token of this card i got an error, see below.

```
 name: 'NOT_AUTHORIZED',
   message: 'Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.',
   debug_id: 'f72e6a41e9a4',
   details: [{
   issue: 'NOT_ENABLED_TO_VAULT_PAYMENT_SOURCE',
   description: 'The API caller or the merchant on whose behalf the API call is initiated is not allowed to vault the given source. Please contact PayPal       customer support for assistance.'
   }]
```

I used the same card to create setup token, but with app based on US country, and it worked fine.
So my question is: Does Paypal Payment Method Tokens Api allowed in switzerland account, if yes than how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a list of countries that can process card directly with PayPal's REST API, see [its "Advanced" documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/#link-eligibility).

Since you are asking about Switzerland, consider a different solution such as the [Braintree Gateway](https://www.braintreepayments.com/country-selection) or the [basic/standard PayPal integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/).

Comment: Can i combine Braintree Gateway with PayPal. For example can i do payments using native paypal api with cards that had been vaulting by Braintree Gateway .

Comment: No, but you'd never want to do that. If you have access to Braintree you'll do all your processing with them.